# Is it necessary to set ViewBinding to null in Fragment's onDestroy()?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

Is it necessary to set ViewBinding to null in Fragment's onDestroy()? Sometimes I see that thing in tutorials. Is it really necessary?

Comment: You mean `onDestroyView`? (not `onDestroy`)

Comment: As is mentioned in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding): _"Fragments outlive their views. Make sure you clean up any references to the binding class instance in the fragment's onDestroyView() method."_

Comment: how if i set it in onDestroy? are there drawbacks if i do that? @Michael

Comment: @Aorstab memory leaks. You can easily google it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is necessary and a really good practice, specially in Android where memory restrictions are huge, you really need to take care of cleaning up resources as and when you are done with them. `ViewBinding` will generate a custom `ViewBinding` class which will keep references to all your `views` inside `Fragment`, if ViewBinding is not cleared or set to null, it won't be eligible for `GC`, thereby holding all the views in memory even though you are not using it, leading to memory leaks. So yes, it is always better to set it to `null` at the end of life cycle.

Comment: Should I do that after or before "super.onDestroyView()"?

Comment: does not really matter unless you do it in `onDestroyView`

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, I'm not really sold on this theory, is there any evidence that supports it?

I'm asking this, because if the ViewBinding class is created inside the fragment, then it will live for as long as the fragment does and will be destroyed along with the fragment since it is a part of the fragment.

Also setting a var to null doesn't necessarily guarantee the GC will clean it. A var could be null but still reachable.

Comment: @Tharkius Indeed, but here the ViewBinding is linked the to lifecycle of the view, not the lifecycle of the Fragment. That's why it should be cleared when the view is destroyed, not when the fragment is destroyed.

Comment: The Google I/O code does not use this approach though, so it makes me wonder why?

Comment: @Tharkius I think your last statement regarding GC is incorrect. GC will actually clean the binding object since that binding object is unreachable, as the variable pointing to it earlier is now null.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is recommended to set ViewBinding to **null** in `onDestroyView`.

**ViewBinding** is scoped to the lifecycle of the fragment's view (between `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView`).   **i.e.** it is is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView.

Hence, please set the respective ViewBinding to null in fragment's `onDestroyView`.

Comment: What if we are using ViewBinding in the activity? Do we set binding to null in the onDestroy()?

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to clean up references to the both  viewBinding and dataBinding.
For viewBindng it's even mentioned in Android official doc
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Since dataBinding is similar to viewBinding we can use the same technique for it also. Following code snippet is from official doc

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
```

private val binding get() = _binding!!

```
override fun onCreateView(
  inflater: LayoutInflater,
  container: ViewGroup?,
  savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
  _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
  val view = binding.root
  return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
 super.onDestroyView()
 _binding = null
}
```

Comment: The Google I/O App doesn't do this :S