# set data binding null like view binding

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

One of our dear fellow android developer asked that [Is it necessary to set ViewBinding to null in Fragment's onDestroy()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119231/is-it-necessary-to-set-viewbinding-to-null-in-fragments-ondestroy) and the answer was yes. i don't use `view binding` per se, is use [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) mostly for fragment bescause of suggested [single activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) method. But i did not find any reference to set data binding null in `onDestroy` or `onDestroyView`. In data binding we can use `setLifecycleOwner` for our data binding. Life cycle owner can be `this` as the `fragment` itself or `requireActivity`. My two Questions are :

Question 1 :  like `view binding` do we need to set dataBinding null ? (data binding kinda does view binding's job that's why i'm asking this Question)

Question 2 : if yes then what really `setLifecycleOwner` for ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this article:["Avoiding memory leaks when using Data Binding and View Binding" by Anders Ullnæss](https://proandroiddev.com/avoiding-memory-leaks-when-using-data-binding-and-view-binding-3b91d571c150)  Yes, you have to set a data binding to null in the OnDestroyView() method because a data binding is actually a view binding. Alternatively, you can use the unbind() function.